# Can I install 12.04 from 11.10?

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, upgrade

I'm having trouble with the download for 12.04. Can I download 11.10 and install 12.04 from it? Will it be supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can download the 11.10 iso, install it from a LiveUSB, and upgrade to 12.04 using the Update Manager:

1. Open the Update Manager from the dash
2. In the bottom left corner, press the "Settings" button
3. In the dialog that opens, click on the "Updates" tab
4. At the bottom, select "For any new version" in the dropdown menu for "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:"

Now, when you close the settings, and refresh the Update Manager via the "Check" button, it should alert you that there is a new version to be installed at the top. Press the upgrade button, and you're on your way!

---

Sources: [Upgrade Ubuntu - ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade)